# How to convert a Model class into a MultiPart Form Data with Retrofit?

Tags: android, post, retrofit, multipartform-data

The API expects the following format with multipart/form data:

```
{
    "salesreq[ref]": "123",
    "salesreq[pdate]": "123",
    "salesreq[dealer_id]": "123",
    "salesreq[sorders_attributes]": [
    {
        "product_id": "123",
        "uprice": "123",
        "quantity": "123"
    },
    {
        "product_id": "123",
        "uprice": "123",
        "quantity": "123"
    },
    {
        "product_id": "123",
        "uprice": "123",
        "quantity": "123"
    }
    ]
}
```

My model object looks like this:

```
public class NewReq
{

    @SerializedName("salesreq[ref]")
    @Expose
    private String salesreqRef;
    @SerializedName("salesreq[pdate]")
    @Expose
    private String salesreqPdate;
    @SerializedName("salesreq[dealer_id]")
    @Expose
    private String salesreqDealerId;
    @SerializedName("salesreq[sorders_attributes]")
    @Expose
    private List<SalesreqSordersAttributes> salesreqSordersAttributes = null;

    public String getSalesreqRef()
    {
        return salesreqRef;
    }

    public void setSalesreqRef(String salesreqRef)
    {
        this.salesreqRef = salesreqRef;
    }

    public String getSalesreqPdate()
    {
        return salesreqPdate;
    }

    public void setSalesreqPdate(String salesreqPdate)
    {
        this.salesreqPdate = salesreqPdate;
    }

    public String getSalesreqDealerId()
    {
        return salesreqDealerId;
    }

    public void setSalesreqDealerId(String salesreqDealerId)
    {
        this.salesreqDealerId = salesreqDealerId;
    }

    public List<SalesreqSordersAttributes> getSalesreqSordersAttributes()
    {
        return salesreqSordersAttributes;
    }

    public void setSalesreqSordersAttributes(List<SalesreqSordersAttributes> salesreqSordersAttributes)
    {
        this.salesreqSordersAttributes = salesreqSordersAttributes;
    }
}
```

My API call using Retrofit looks something like this:

```
@POST("/salereqs.json")
Call<ResponseBody> newRequisition(@Body NewReq textPart);
```

The above call doesn't work obviously since the service expects multi-part/form data and I'm sending it using the @body annotation (pardon my lack of understanding of REST APIs).

My question:

**How do I send multi-part data by using my model class instead of manually creating a string and passing it as a MultipartBody.Part object?**

Also, is it possible to add an image upload in this very function?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

From  Retrofit's [homepage](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) you just need to add the `@Multipart` annotation and use `@RequestBody` to send data. And yes it is possible to add image upload. Just construct the request body and add it to the function params

Comment: Would you care to explain a bit more? Request body has a writeTo function. How would that help here?

Answer (score 0):

The way your API call works at the bottom is exactly how I pass data to my API. So that method can work, but if your backend expects something different then it may fail.

```
@POST("/salereqs.json")
Call<ResponseBody> newRequisition(
        @Body DeficiencyUpdateObject object);
```

Here is an alternative that passes a file.

```
@Multipart
@POST("/salereqs.json")
Call<ResponseBody> newRequisition(
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
        @Part("salesreq[ref]") RequestBody salesreq,
        @Part("salesreq[pdate]") RequestBody pdate,
        @Part("salesreq[dealer_id]") RequestBody dealer_id,
        @Part("salesreq[sorders_attributes]") RequestBody sorders_attributes);
```

Perhaps its possible that Retrofit is missing a converter factory? `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`

Also a great way to help debug Retrofit calls is with a logging library, here is a sample to help anyone start to dig deeper.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
```

Comment: How is this answer to "How do I send multi-part data by using my model class instead of manually creating a string and passing it as a MultipartBody.Part object?"?

Comment: Well he was worried he had to convert his model into a string which he didn't want. My code shows that what they did is the same as my code (which means they might be mis-debugging). As well I showed how you can use MultipartBody.Part to pass data to which includes sending an image (which they asked). I additionally pointed out that there could be an error with their Converter Factory and as a bonus a way to debug errors incase his problem was something else.